# InfoPath complex file attachment

Tags: 2013, infopath, form, list-form

Using SP2013, IP2013

I've been searching fruitlessly for a way to easily attach multiple files to an InfoPath form (for a custom list). Basically what has been asked of me is to make a form for a business process that has multiple spots to upload/attach documents like schedules and mission statements inline as the user fills out the form. I know with a repeating table I can allow multiple attachments, but they can't be divided up to display next to their appropriate line items, they are all simply connected to a single field and an ever-expanding control that has a tendency to wreck the form layout.

I should mention this is a very large form with some very complicated formatting, and it will be (hopefully) holding a lot of attached documents, so it's fairly critical to its success that I come up with some way to make this happen. It's also going to be published to thousands of different sites in the collection, so hard-coding links won't work (they have to reflect the site they are a part of without user intervention).

If you need any more clarification let me know, I'll be as helpful as I can! Thanks in advance for any advice!

**Edit for clarity:** Here's an example of what I'm talking about. The circled buttons are where a documents would need to be attached. There would be about a dozen places on the form that would require attached documents, though they don't necessarily have to be buttons like in the image, just need to not destroy the formatting. The form itself is for tracking project progress, and will be a part of a site template that will be published for each such project (hence not being able to hard-code values into it).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I'm aware of is to set up a document library for each place you want to attach documents and then have the button open that library in a new tab. InfoPath attachments encode the documents into the form itself which makes them not searchable and affects the form's load time, so would not be recommended in your case. It's only one extra click for the user, and it gives you more control over the documents themselves, like being able to search them or subject them to workflows.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but it seems to be the ONLY answer none the less. I'll just have to tell my users to suck it up and deal with the extra click/tab :p I rather like the idea of being able to index them too